# Approach to modeling a fan

Tags: modeling, modifiers, workflow

Does anyone have a good approach to modeling a fan like the type below? Specifically, all the loops are giving me trouble. There must be an easy way to create an array of rings like this. Then on top of that, they conform to the shape of the inner wires (the non-concentric ones radiating from the center that are perpendicular to the others).

[image]

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just an example, you should get some ideas for your fan after this.

- Make sure you are in object mode
- Add a sphere. Shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>
  [image: Sphere showing last operator adjust entry]
- In the last operator adjust panel, in the lower left, adjust the number of segments and rings. All are just approximate numbers...
- Scale in Z to 'flatten' the sphere. Shortcut <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and move the mouse to scale. Left click when you're done.
  [image: Scale in Z to 'flatten' the sphere]
- Enter Edit Mode. Shortcut <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Deselect all. Shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd>
- Select only the segments ('spokes') Description TBD
- Part the selection to create a second object. Shortcut <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
  [[image: Select 'spokes' and separate3]
- This creates a second object. If you left the first object with the default name of *Sphere*, the object with just the spokes will be called *Sphere.001* for instance.
- Reselect the original spokes.
- Delete the edges and faces (but not vertices) Shortcut: <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>
- Add a subdivision modifier, if desired.
  [image: Steps to delete and subdivide]
- Return to Object mode
- Convert to a curve and adjust the curve's parameters.
  [image: Converting to a curve]
- You have to experiment with the curve to get your desired shape with minimum tries.

Comment: Hi Ramesh, thanks for the answer. Please always prefer typing text here in the body of the post, rather than put it into your images. That way it can be indexed and searched for whereas in the images no one can find it by searching. it is also easier to read and  fix mistakes, typos, or update in case things change in the future. Could you edit your post to include all descriptions as text here? Thanks

Comment: Yeah this is a really good method, just harder to read.

Comment: Hi Ramesh, I've edited your answer to _mostly_ move the text into the answer as text.  You might want to look at what I did and add the parts I didn't get to.

Comment: Thanks for editing my answer @MartyFouts

Comment: It is better and I'll remember what you said before answering again @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect, I'll continue experimenting with it.